# Validity of axes renaming

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, vectors, vector-analysis

The position vector is $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$.

$\vec{A}$ is a vector field, $\vec{A}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$

and $C$ is a constant.

We have the function

$$f=f(a_1x,a_2x,a_3x,Cx^2).$$

Can one then say, that because axes can be renamed, we can write the arguments $f$ as

$$f=f(a_1y,a_2y,a_3y,Cy^2), or$$
$$f=f(a_1z,a_2z,a_3z,Cz^2)?$$

Should be correct, right? But can we then write $f$ in vector notation

$$f=f(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{r},C\vec{r}^2)?$$

I am unsure if the last line is correct, because it kind of replaces $f:R\rightarrow R$ with $f:R^3\rightarrow R$?

Thus, the question is,

Is this expression correct: $f=f(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{r},C\vec{r}^2)?$

Comment: No, I think $f=f(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{r},C\vec{r}^2)$ is not correct because $\vec A\cdot\vec r$ means the **scalar product** of two vectors, which gives the sum of the products of its components, all in *one* argument. Although, the first expression separates the components by a comma `,`, when you are renaming it by a plus `+`.

Comment: What about $f(a_1x,a_2x,a_3x,Cx^2)$. This is still a function of one variable, namely $x$, correct?

Comment: It seems the question may also be about making a distinction between variables and arguments...?

Comment: You can replace $x$ with any letter you want, but from $f=f(a_1x,a_2x,a_3x,Cx^2)$ you can not group the variables because $f$ has $4$ arguments and $f(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{r},C\vec{r}^2)$ has only two, namely $\vec A\cdot\vec r=a_1x+a_2y+a_3z$ and $C\vec r^2=Cx+Cy+Cz$.

Comment: I agree; coudln't two of them be multiplied by zero? Then they will be absent, and only 2 arguments remain.

Comment: No (and I think this is the answer of another of your questions): two functions are equal if they both has the same domain, codomain/image/range and the exact formula. As you can see, $\vec f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^4\mid\vec f(x,y,z)=(a_1x,a_2x,a_3x,Cx^2)$ is not the same as $\vec g:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^4\mid\vec g(x,y,z)=(a_1x+a_2y+a_3z,Cx+Cy+Cz,0,0)$ because for example if $x=0$ then $\vec f(0,y,z)=(0,0,0,0)$ but $\vec g(0,y,z)=(a_2y+a_3z,C_y+C_z,0,0)$: they don't have the same formula.

Comment: Even if the $\vec f$ that I propose only contains the $x$ as a variable, the domain is different, so in this case $\vec f\neq\vec g$ too.

Comment: Werp, in this case I forgot that we have $\vec r^2$ not $\vec r$ but it has the same effect. Sorry to forgot that.